# Using SASS on a Red Hat Linux box with PHP but not Ruby

Tags: php, sass, redhat

I have been looking into SASS on and off for a while now. I think the benefits of such a system could be great, as it will allow the use of global variables and other such features.

It will also allow me to have multiple CSS files that get compiled into one, which (as we all know) means only one HTTP request.

The problem is, we use a Red Hat Linux environment with PHP to run Joomla-based templates and I have been informed that I need to find a Ruby alternative. Also, anything that we install on the servers must be in the Red Hat repositories.

Is there any way around this for SASS? Do I have to find an alternative? And if so, what would the clever people of Stack Overflow recommend?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need Ruby to run SASS in PHP, because PHP's own compiler for SASS is available. For this, you can download the package from https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to only install Ruby/Sass on your development machine (I have a virtual box running BSD on my laptop).  Compile local and push the finished CSS to your production machine.

You might also look into a Windows compiler like Scout (never used it myself):  http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/